# Unexpectedly found nil accessing custom cell outside function

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift5

Trying to access the custom cell of UITableView outside the defaults methods to update data, it is crashing below is my code:

```
    let cell = tblAddPlayer.cellForRow(at: indexPosition) as! DropDownCell. // Crashing here..
    cell.txtFieldSearchCity.text = city
    
    tblAddPlayer.reloadRows(at: [indexPosition], with: .none)
```

I just need to update data of one cell, based on the selection made from next view controller. So, passing back data to previous viewController and need to update that value in UITableViewCell. Thus trying to access custom cell but getting crash and error. Please guide what's wrong here.

Crash and error:

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file /PlayerViewController.swift, line 111
```

Comment: Calling `cellForRow(at` is dangerous because `indexPosition` can be off screen. As you are reloading the row anyway update the model which updates the cell. This assumes that the value of `txtFieldSearchCity` is being maintained in the model.

Comment: Don't force unwrap - `cellForRow(at:)` may well return `nil` if that row isnt visible. You should just update the data model and then reload the row

Comment: @Paulw11 there is no data model, it's a form to be filled by typing or selecting value from dropdown. Here is dropdown case where data selected from next view controller and passed back through delegates to previous VC where needs to update on cell

Comment: You have to have a data model; Tableview cells are just *views*; You can't rely on them to store data

Comment: @Paulw11 I have created data model to get parameters, but not getting how to populate model class from UITableViewCell